# Get Frequently Contacted List

Tags: android

I'm aware of how to list contacts as a whole within android but is there a way to somehow get only the most frequently contacted list?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no current way to do this without manually extracting the data from the contact list and attempting to compute this yourself.

Here is an example of an attempt at doing so:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21426796/android-get-frequent-contact-list